# creating clickable tiles with html div's

Tags: button, html, size

Was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction of creating a bunch of tiles using the html div elements. I need 9 tiles in total to fill the entire screen. My problem is that the height attribute does not fill the screen and each tile stacks ontop of each other rather then sitting side by side.

```
 <body>
      <div id='container'>
             <div id='button1' onclick='...' width='33%' height='33%'>image</div>
             <div id='button2' onclick='...' width='33%' height='33%'>image</div>
             <div id='button3' onclick='...' width='33%' height='33%'>image</div>
             <div id='button4' onclick='...' width='33%' height='33%'>image</div>
             <div id='button5' onclick='...' width='33%' height='33%'>image</div>
             <div id='button6' onclick='...' width='33%' height='33%'>image</div>
             <div id='button7' onclick='...' width='33%' height='33%'>image</div>
             <div id='button8' onclick='...' width='33%' height='33%'>image</div>
             <div id='button9' onclick='...' width='33%' height='33%'>image</div>
       </div>


 </body>
```

Im a noob to HTML are their any best practices and could someone point me in the right direction to achieve said result??

Comment: You can start by putting the sizes in style sheets (preferably in a separate CSS file), instead of using these width and height properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In CSS you can start with giving the HTML itself a height of 100%, like this:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Then, you can specify the sizes of the divs

Container:

```
#container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Tiles:

```
#container div {
    width: 33%;
    height: 33%;
    float: left;
}
```

Float left makes them align next to each other. When there is not enough space they will wrap to the next line.

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/GolezTrol/BDb5K/